# MySQL : Restore dump file

Tags: mysql, restore

I have a single .sql file which is 800MB in size and contains a few of databases including tables and datas.

The problem is, how to restore this kind of dump since there is no `CREATE DATABASE` syntax in the file?

I try `mysql> -u root -p --all-database < c:\data.sql` but no joy.

Comment: Does the .sql file contain the CREATE TABLE entries (i.e. is it just the CREATE DATABASE entries that are missing)?

Comment: Yes, it does. Only 2 command are exists `CREATE TABLE` and `INSERT INTO table`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Conducted a backup of the following.

```
mysqldump -u xxx -p --all-database > c:\data.sql
```

Or, in the database unit

```
mysqldump -u xxx -p --databases db_name > c:\data.sql
```

Recovery in the following code.

```
mysql -u root -p < c:\data.sql
```